# NullPointerException on timer

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

//swing class, An object named foo(frame showing time each second)

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        
        @Override
        public void  run() {
            
            if(object != null){
                  object.getProperty()... //->here NullPointerException
            }
        }
     }, 0, 1000);

  //another class

  foo.setObject(null)
```

is it possible that foo.setObject(null) happens after if(object!=null) and before object.getproperty()??

Comment: For one, you're using the wrong Timer class. Do not use `java.util.Timer` with Swing GUI's but rather use `javax.swing.Timer` which is thread-safe. For another, you are not posting the key information required to allow others to be able to help debug a NPE (NullPointerException), one of the most common issues seen on this site. Study the duplicate and consider improving your question if still stuck.

Comment: So, always include the full stack trace text with your NPE question, and highlight the lines that the stack trace indicates throws the exception (which you may kind of be doing, but without the stack trace, it's difficult to tell), and also what variable is definitely null when the exception occurs, as per your debugger.  Also, look into posting [mre] code with your question so that we can reproduce the problem ourselves.

Comment: and to answer your direct question, yes, it is very possible for a null check, such as written above, to fail in a multi-threading environment if threading isn't handled correctly. One solution is to use synchronization, but more importantly for this example, simply changing your Timer class to the correct one will likely remove this very risk.

Comment: Thanks, i will try with the other timer.  i tried with synchornized method but app frezze

Comment: Thanks. The javax.swing.Timer works fine

Comment: You're welcome. The Swing timer should work because all the key code is called on a single thread, the Swing Event Thread. For more details on this, please review [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)